# Laravel Event Source with MongoDB

Tags: laravel, mongodb, event-sourcing

I have a project that implements an event source using https://github.com/spatie/laravel-event-sourcing. And now I want to use MongoDB to store the event store, using https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb. But I get stuck to implement both. Both packages required to extends their own class. This is my custom model for the event source.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\MongoDB;

use Spatie\EventSourcing\StoredEvents\Models\EloquentStoredEvent;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;

class StoredEvent extends EloquentStoredEvent
{
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $collection = 'events';
}
```

I only extend the spatie event source class, but get stuck when extends the mongodb class. Any suggestion? I cannot change the event source package

Comment: PHP doesn't support multiple inheritance so you can only ever extend one class however , in a non-ideal manner you can always just "copy-paste" the [stored event model](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-event-sourcing/blob/master/src/StoredEvents/Models/EloquentStoredEvent.php) in your project but have it extend the MongoDB model and then all your models can extend that. It's not ideal but you can probably open a suggestion for spatie to resolve this differently e.g. provide traits instead of a base model so you would be free to extend any base model you need

Comment: I've tried the "copy-paste" method but still, that doesn't work. Because the custom model that I used must extend the spatie event source. @apokryfos

Comment: It's probably best to open a GitHub issue for them then.